# How do I edit data frames in a list.file

Tags: r, loops, purrr, data-cleaning

I have created a list of excel files with the following instructions:

```
setwd(folder1/folder2)

bases <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

bases.list <- lapply(bases, read_excel)
```

The names of the data frames are like these: jan20student.xlsx, feb20student.xlsx, ......, jan21student.xlsx. The number indicates the year 2020 or 2021. All data frames have the same variables. I want to keep specific variables and create a categorical variable of age ( [10, 20) = young and [20, 40) = adult) in each data frame. I would also like to save each data frame with a name like jan20names.xlsx, etc. Could you give me some suggestions for coding the instructions?

I tried with the following code:

```
result.list <- map_dfr(bases.list, select(id, exp, name, age))
```

But it does not work

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code -

```
library(dplyr)

bases <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

purrr::map(bases, ~.x %>% 
            read_excel %>%
            select(id, exp, name, age) %>%
            mutate(age_cat = case_when(between(age, 10, 20) ~ 'young', 
                                       between(age, 20, 40) ~ 'adult')) %>%
            writexl::write_xlsx(sub('student', 'names', .x)))
```

Comment: Ronak Shah, thanks for your help. It works perfectly. I have two questions. It was used ~ at the begining of the code (purrr::map(bases, ~.x %>%), and when the files are saved it was not necessary the ~ [sub('student', 'names', .x)]. When I have to use ~?. Could you recommend me some material to learn the use of the purrr library? I set the working directory as follows: setwd(folder1/folder2), but if want to save in a different  folder, for example, folder3/folder4. How could I indicate a new route in your code? Thanks

Comment: `~` is used to apply a function in `map`. The file saving code is still inside the `map` so you don't have to use it again. To add a new route to save the files you can use `writexl::write_xlsx(paste0('folder3/folder4/', sub('student', 'names', .x))))`